I have a question regarding the subscribe method
I have the following code which I am studying
 getUser(): void {

this.service.getUsers().subscribe(
  {
    next: (resposta) => {
      console.log(resposta)
      this.users = resposta
    },

   
    error: (erroo: any) => {
      console.log('ocorreu algum erro')
      console.log(erroo)
    }
  }
)
}

my question is about what does '(answer)' mean after next, is it an array function?

"resposta", you mean - it's the name that you, the programmer, gives to the response argument (the incoming subscription data) so that it can be referred to, like in the console.log() call here.

when I say this.users = resposta , am I saying that 'users' is receiving this response from next? @500-internalServerError

Yes, that's exactly right.

getUsers() returns an RxJS Observable.
Observables are meant to emit values multiple times, next is called for each value.
But in the case of an http request they emit only once and finish. So next will be called just once on successful response.
You could rewrite as:
async loadUser(): void {
  try {
    const resposta = await firstValueFrom(this.service.getUsers())
    console.log(resposta)
    this.users = resposta
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.log('ocorreu algum erro')
    console.log(erroo)
  }
}

